# How to put else part in @available(iOS 15.0, *) declaration for stored property?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, attributes

Before iOS 15 I had a custom class `SelectableButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem` with `isSelected` property which worked perfectly:

```swift
class SelectableButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem {
  var isSelected = false {
    didSet {
      // ... some custom action
    }
  }
}
```

iOS 15 and Xcode 13 introduced `isSelected` property in `UIBarButtonItem`, so for iOS 15 I don't need to declare it anymore.

`@available(iOS 15.0, *)` allows to declare properties available in iOS 15 and above.

```swift
class SelectableButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem {
  @available(iOS 15.0, *)
  override var isSelected: Bool {
    get { super.isSelected }
    set {
      super.isSelected = newValue
      // ... some custom action
    }
  }
}
```

I can't put `if @available ... else` here, as it is not allowed at the property declaration level.

How do I declare not overridden `isSelected` property only for iOS 14 and below?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64797366/stored-properties-cannot-be-marked-potentially-unavailable-with-available ? Use a internal property that will have the iOS15 value or the old one if needed?

Comment: Thanks [Larme](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1801544/larme), for a while I renamed my custom property from `isSelected` to `isButtonSelected`. But still would like to know whether there is a way I can continue to use `isSelected` everywhere.

Comment: @DenisBystruev Why can't you just keep the `override` without an `@available` check, and then do `#available` checks within the getter and setter?

Comment: @DenisBystruev Btw, use @ so people get a notification from replies - just writing their name doesn't ping them